# How to remove first column from export CSV in ag grid in angular2 while exporting csv?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, export-csv

// This code doesn't remove first column

```
let params = {};  

params = { allColumns: false };  

this.agGridOptions.columnDefs[0]['hide'] = true; // To remove first column  

this.agGridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use columnKeys to provide the list of columns that you want to export.

So if you want to export all the visible columns except the first, get the list of visible columns using `getAllDisplayedColumns()`, then remove the first item from the list and pass this as the `columnKeys` to `exportDataAsCsv(params)` method.

Comment: For furthar help

let columnsKeys = this.agGridOptions.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns();
    let columnIds: Array<any> = [];
    columnsKeys.forEach(keys => {
      let columnName: string = keys.getColId();
      if (columnName != '0' && columnName) {
        columnIds.push(columnName);
      }
    });
    return columnIds;

params['columnKeys'] = columnIds;

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 exportCsv() {       
    var excelParams = {
        columnKeys: ['firstName', 'middleName','lastName', 'dob'],
        allColumns: false,
        fileName: 'Student List.csv',
        skipHeader: false,
        customHeader: 'Student List' + '\n',
        customFooter: '\n \n Total No.Of Students :' + this.gridOptions.api.getModel().getRowCount() + ' \n'
    }
    this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(excelParams);
}
```

Mention the columns which want to be displayed in Excel should be defined in columnKeys